# AngularJS Syntax - John Papa's Bindable up-top Syntax is Ambiguous

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am reading this excellent styling guide by [John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide). A little bit down the list, he talks about 'Bindable Members Up Top'.

To quote his example, he says **avoid this**:

```
/* avoid */
function Sessions() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.gotoSession = function() {
      /* ... */
    };
    vm.refresh = function() {
      /* ... */
    };
    vm.search = function() {
      /* ... */
    };
    vm.sessions = [];
    vm.title = 'Sessions';
```

and instead **use this**:

```
/* recommended */
function Sessions() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.gotoSession = gotoSession;
    vm.refresh = refresh;
    vm.search = search;
    vm.sessions = [];
    vm.title = 'Sessions';

    ////////////

    function gotoSession() {
      /* */
    }

    function refresh() {
      /* */
    }

    function search() {
      /* */
    }
```

While this is very clean, it poses one problem. What if your function had arguments? Say that in the example above, the function `search` gets a query: `function search(str)`. To be able to do this as a one-liner, then what he recommends looks like:

```
function Sessions() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.search = search;

    //////////

    function search(str) {

    }
```

The problem is then when you look at the top `vm.search = search` you are not sure what is passed to the function and you would need to scroll down to the function `function search(str)` to find out.

Can someone expand on this for me?

**EDIT**

I created [an issue on the page](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide/issues/133#issuecomment-63879667) asking John himself to respond to this.

Comment: That is a good question, but I am not sure if stack overflow is the best place to get an answer.  In the past we have had questions like yours about the styleguide and found that if you put an issue against his style guide repo, he will answer it.

Comment: @user1545858, okay thanks. I will put an issue and see what he says.

Comment: No problems.  I would be interested in the answer, so if you can either repost or put the link to the issue here, it would be appreciated.

Comment: @user1545858, here you go. I updated the question with the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IDE should be able to handle that, or you could use [TypeScript's](http://typescriptlang.org) interfaces to both keep a "up top" and clean implementation in the class itself.

I'd recommend Visual Studio (if you do c# / asp.net stuff as well) or Web Storm if not. Web Storm is very cheap and a great editor for web work. Sublime might have some plugins as well.

Comment: So basically you are saying that I should be using documentation like jsDoc, to define what is being passed to `search` on the top line?

Comment: I haven't used jsDoc but if it lets you hint at parameters then yeah that should work. Ideally your IDE would be able to infer what search is and what parameters it takes

Comment: Also,  I don't think it's generally a good idea to write a code that is understandable if you view it with a specific editor. A good code should be well documented and written so that even a simple notepad can be used to read it

Comment: @Kousha sure, but you can easily see what methods are available to that file at glance without an editor. To make a new call to that method (and know its parameters) having an IDE would help a lot. Or document it with Typescript interfaces or others. Typescript will help you with more than just documentation though